# Webpack - bundle all node modules except one in angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I made a webapp with angular. I want server side rendering with Angular Universal.
The best way to build such a server is by using webpack, this is the standard configuration which works for most of the cases:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/node_modules/],
  mode: 'none',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /server-local/ }]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

But I got a problem: I use the node module pug-mailer in my server and it uses uglify-js as dependency and not dev dependencies. Webpack has no support in bundling uglify-js, so the only way I found to solve this problem was this:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  ... //the rest is unchanged
};
```

But it cannot be accepted: with this, all node_modules are not bundled and I have to keep the entire node_modules dir in my production server.

Is there a way to bundle all the node_modules in only one file except for uglify-js?

The result I want is this:

```
dist
----server.js //built with webpack, contains all node_modules except uglify-js
----other dists folder
node_modules
----uglify-js //Only this dependency in node_modules
```